# How to setup properties of a custom widget through a dialog just like QColor in QtDesigner

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer, color-picker

I'm using QtDesigner to develop something. I define some custom widgets for QtDesigner, and the custom widgets have some custom pyqtproperties which could be edited in QtDesigner. For the moment, QStringList, int, str, float.... all the basic data types as pyqtproperty worked perfectly. But that's not enough for me, there is a dynamic list with bool values. Hot to create a pyqtproperty which could popup a dialog then I can edit the dynamic list which radiobutton? I know it is possible because there is a default property 'color' which will popup a dialog used to select a color.